# API format in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm working with API of a delivery service. They provide an opportunity to test the API on their website, where the following code works perfectly:

```
{
    "modelName": "InternetDocument",
    "calledMethod": "documentsTracking",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Documents": [
            "20450000773554",
            "20450000773555"
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I try to convert it to PHP format, I don't know what to do with the arrays of 'methodProperties' in PHP syntax.

```
$data = array(
    'modelName' => 'InternetDocument',
    'calledMethod' => 'documentsTracking',
    'methodProperties' => ???
);
```

Can you please help me to convert the code to PHP correctly?

Comment: ... You already did the right thing with the main object itself, why is a child object stumping you?

Comment: 'methodProperties' => ["Documents" => ["20450000773554", "20450000773555"] ]

Comment: OR `'methodProperties' => array('Documents' => array('20450000773554', '20450000773555'))` for the old-school `array()` users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions work:

This as `JSON` string:

```
{
    "modelName": "InternetDocument",
    "calledMethod": "documentsTracking",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Documents": [
            "20450000773554",
            "20450000773555"
        ]
    }
}
```

is equivalent to this in `PHP`:

```
array(
    'modelName'    => 'InternetDocument',
    'calledMethod' => 'documentsTracking',
    'methodProperties' => array(
       'Documents' => array(
         "20450000773554",
         "20450000773555"
       )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    'modelName' => 'InternetDocument',
    'calledMethod' => 'documentsTracking',
    'methodProperties' => array('Documents' => array('20450000773554', '20450000773554'))
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON :**

```
  $json =  {
        "modelName": "InternetDocument",
        "calledMethod": "documentsTracking",
        "methodProperties": {
            "Documents": [
                "20450000773554",
                "20450000773555"
            ]
        }
    }
```

the data of this format is known as `JSON`(Javascript object notation),So,If you want to access it by using `PHP` you have to decode it using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) predefined function in `PHP`.

**PHP:**

```
$decoded_string = json_decode($json);
```

now use,

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decoded_string);
```

you get the following data in the form of array and you can easily parse this data in your application.

```
array(
    'modelName'    => 'InternetDocument',
    'calledMethod' => 'documentsTracking',
    'methodProperties' => array(
       'Documents' => array(
         "20450000773554",
         "20450000773555"
       )
    )
);
```